# Why is .NET separate from the Windows Operating System?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, c++, ado.net

Since .NET is so important to Windows, and Microsoft delivers both .NET and Windows, why doesn't Microsoft simply make .NET part of Windows?

Comment: Flagged to be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: They do, and it is. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: It ships with it, so I would consider it a part of the OS.  It's not living in the kernel somewhere, but neither is `user32` which is/ws the native GUI API for something like 15 years (it was `user` before the advent of Windows 32-bit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET does come bundled with Windows; e.g., .NET 3.5 came with Windows 7. Of course, Microsoft needs to make it available as a separate download for older computers. Newer versions of .NET are released through Microsoft Update, so I'd say it's pretty well streamlined with the OS.